# Scriptella and CSV column headers that contain spaces

Tags: csv, etl, scriptella

I am attempting to move data from CSV files into a database table, and I'd like to use the column header names in the script.  For example:

```
<connection id="csvin" driver="csv" url="/path/to/file.csv" />
<connection id="dbout" driver="h2" url="connection string" />
<query connection-id="csvin">
  <script connection-id="out">
    INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (?column one,?column five,?column eight)
  </script>
</query>
```

I get a SQL syntax error from the above.  If I instead use the SQL statement

```
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (?1, ?5, ?8)
```

Then it works.  But I'd really rather use the column headers.  Due to logistical reasons, I cannot have the column header names changed to not contain spaces.  Is there any way to accomplish using the names that have spaces?

I have tried escaping the spaces, quoting the names, using brackets, and using unicode notation (`\u0020`), but have had no luck so far.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately special symbols in variable names cannot be escaped, but Scriptella provides a utility method to achieve a similar effect. See [EtlVariable.getParameter](http://scriptella.javaforge.com/docs/api/scriptella/core/EtlVariable.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29)

In your case, simply use `?{etl.getParameter('column one')}`

Comment: Thank you for bringing it up. It's definitely not obvious. I forgot there is already FAQ entry http://scriptella.javaforge.com/faq.html#COLUMN_SPACES